# How to find file encoding type or convert any encoding type to UTF-8 in shell?

Tags: shell, encoding, utf-8, sh

I get text file of random encoding format, `usc-2le`, `ansi`, `utf-8`, `usc-2be` etc. I have to convert this files to  `utf8`.

For conversion am using the following command

`iconv options -f from-encoding -t utf-8 <inputfile > outputfile`

But if incorrect `from-encoding` is provided, then incorrect file is generated.

I want a way to find the input file encoding type.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please improve your question by telling more: How do you get that file? From whom and from where? What is that file likely to contain?

Comment: file is placed in some fixed input folder.

Comment: That should go into the question (not in a comment). But *who* placed that file? Ask him what encoding he used! "Random encoding" don't exist (you mean that the encoding is unknown to you, and you should do whatever it takes to find which one has been used, or else ignore that file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do file encoding conversion with

```
vim -c "set encoding=utf8" -c "set fileencoding=utf8" -c "wq" filename
```

It's working fine , no need to give source encoding.

Comment: How can be that answer is the accepted one?? This just validates that a file is UTF8 without changing its UTF8 encoding! and that answer don't answer the question at all (which is about some *unknown* encoding)

Comment: That command don't change (or discover) the encoding of the unknown input file

Answer (score 3):

On Linux you could try using [file(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) on your unknown input file. Most of the time it would guess the encoding correctly. Or else try *several* encodings to `iconv` till you "feel" that the result is acceptable (for example if you know that the file is some Russian poetry, you might try [KOI-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI_character_encodings), UTF-8, etc.... till you recognize a good Russian poem).

But [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) is a nightmare and can be ambiguous. The provider of the file should tell you what encoding he used (and there is no way to get that encoding reliably and in all cases : there are some byte sequences which would be valid and interpreted *differently* with various encodings).

<sup>(notice that the [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) protocol mentions and explicits the encoding)</sup>

In 2017, better use [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/) (and you should follow that http://utf8everywhere.org/  link) so ask your human partners to send you UTF-8 (hopefully most of your files are in UTF-8, since today they all should be).

<sup>(so encoding is more a *social* issue than a technical one)</sup>

> I get text file of random encoding format

Notice   that "random encoding" don't exist. You want and need to find out what [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) (and [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format)) has been used by the provider of that file (so you mean "unknown encoding", not "random" one).

<sup>BTW, do you have a formal, unambiguous, sound and *precise* definition of [*text* file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file), beyond file without zero bytes, or files with few control characters? [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX), [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) source, [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL), [UUencoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding), [shar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar), [XPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_PixMap), and [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) files are all text files, but very different ones!</sup>

You probably want to expect UTF-8, and you might use the [file extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension) as some hint. Knowing the [media-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) could help.

<sup>(so if HTTP has been used to transfer the file, it is important to keep (and trust) the `Content-Type`...; read about [HTTP headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields))</sup>

> [...] then incorrect file is generated.

How do you know that the resulting file is incorrect? You can only know if you have some expectations about that result (e.g. that it contains Russian poetry, not junk characters; but perhaps these junk characters are some [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) to some secret interpreter, or some music represented in weird fashion, or encrypted, etc....). Raw files are just sequences of bytes, you need some extra knowledge to use them (even if you know that they use UTF-8).

Comment: `file` command only returns as `data`, `regular file` or `ascii`. So I need to have surety of input file encoding.

Comment: You can't be certain. You need to ask the person providing the file what encoding has been used. Or you could try several encodings till you *feel* you decoded that file successfully